# Wikipedia API does not give any data back

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to get data from the Wikipedia API but I cannot get data to return. I think the problem is with the URL, but I don't know. I have changed the URL. I had the url as

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&action=opensearch&search=" + searchItem +"&format=json&orgin=*";

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&action=opensearch&search=" + searchItem +"&format=json&orgin=*&callback=?";

```js
$(function(){

    
    $('#search-click').click(function(){ 
     var searchItem = document.getElementById('input-search').value;
     console.log(searchItem);
     console.log('clicked');

     var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&action=opensearch&search=" + searchItem +"&format=json&callback=?";
     $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: url,
      async: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data){
       console.log('Success.');
      },
      error: function(error){
       console.log('Error. Cannot Load Data.');
      }

     });

    });
});
```

```css
body, html{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #16324f;
 color: #d6d9ce;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
} 
h1{
 text-align: center;
 color: #d6d9ce;
 font-size: 50px;
}
h3{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #d6d9ce;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.center div{
 margin: 0 30%;
}
form{
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px 10px;
 display: inline-flex;
}
#search-click img{
 padding-left: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#input-search{
 padding: 10px;
 width: 400px;
 color: #16324f;
}
input{
 border-radius: 25px;
}
#random-search img{
 margin: 0 50%;
}
footer{
 margin-top: 100px;
}
footer a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #d6d9ce;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Wikipedia Viewer</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wikipediaviewer.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header><h1>Wikipedia Viewer</h1></header>
 <div class="center">
  <div>
   <form id="form">
    <input id="input-search" type="text" name="search">
    <a id="search-click" href=""><img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/51/f49d37/search-filled.png"></a>
   </form>
  </div>
  <div>
   <h3>Random Search</h3>
   <a id="random-search" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/51/d6d9ce/search-filled.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
   
  <ul id="wikipedia-links"></ul>
 </div>

 <footer>
  <a href="https://icons8.com">Icon pack by Icons8</a>
 </footer>

 <!-- JQUERY -->

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="wikipediaviewer.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this page from an http server? If so, you can't load https content over an http conecction.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same API without UI and it is working fine.

Let me know if I'm missing something, here's the snippet -

```js
$(function() {


  $('#search-click').click(function() {
    var searchItem = document.getElementById('input-search').value;

    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&action=opensearch&search=" + searchItem + "&format=json&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      async: false,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log('Error. Cannot Load Data.');
      }

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input-search" value="JavaScript" />
<input type="button" id="search-click" value="search" />
```